# Without internet connection how hibernate configuration file is validated against the DTD

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, xsd, dtd

To validate the xml we need either dtd or xsd. If we want to validate the xml against the dtd then we need to write this one in Hibernate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Here PUBLIC indicates that **hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd** file is available in network. When we execute the Hibernate program then Hibernate should go to this URL http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd and validate the hibernate-configuration.dtd file.

But my question is without internet connection how hibernate can validate the configuration file??

I know **hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd** file is also available within the hibernate jar. But if it is available in our file system then we need to wtite SYSTEM instead of PUBLIC and we need give the complete absolute path of our file system where **hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd** file is available.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. I tried some thing better by writing the below xml statement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

for mapping files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

and put these two files **hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd** and **hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd** in the tomcat server's bin directory. (I am using apache tomcat server). The server is search these dtd file in its current directory (bin directory). In that way it solved my issue in running my application offline. If any better way is there it is always welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an internet connection if the URL you specify matches the one Hibernate expects.

Hibernate uses an EntityResolver to load the dtd from within the Hibernate jar if the URL matches.

E.g. in Hibernate 3.5, the [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver.html) class:

> ... attempts to resolve various systemId URLs to local classpath lookups
>
> 1. Any systemId URL beginning with http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/ is searched for as a classpath resource in the classloader which loaded the Hibernate classes.
> 2. Any systemId URL using classpath as the scheme (i.e. starting with classpath:// is searched for as a classpath resource using first the current thread context classloader and then the classloader which loaded the Hibernate classes.
>
> Any entity references which cannot be resolved in relation to the above rules result in returning null, which should force the SAX reader to handle the entity reference in its default manner.

In Hibernate 3.6, the URL prefix changed to http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ as shown in the updated [DTDEntityResolver](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver.html)

In your case, if you are using a pre-3.6 Hibernate jar, your specification will use the external DTD. You can either update Hibernate, or use the correct URL for your version of Hibernate.

If you want to be sure you are using the DTD in the Hibernate jar, you can use:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```